# Error occured while connecting to cloud sql from android studio

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to connect to cloud sql from app engine using cloud back-end java servlet in android studio. But I got error in getting connection from **DriverManager**.

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:google:mysql://<id:<sql-id>/database",
                  "myuser","password");
```

and driver is

```
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");
```

Please assist me if fixing this error...

Comment: What is the error? Do you have the jars in class path?

Answer (score 0):

The `com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver` driver and `jdbc:google:mysql` connection string *only* work from Google App Engine. When connecting from your development workstation you should use the plain MySQL java connector (ie `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` and `jdbc:mysql`). You will need to authorize you workstation's IP address and add an IP address to your Cloud SQL instance to connect to.

For more information follow the guide at https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/external.

Comment: **Actually** i got it,problem is with some user database permission for using database in appengine(Localhost for cloud sql database) type code in cloud sql database    ` grant all privileges on databasename.* to 'user'@'localhost' identified by 'password'; `

Answer (score 0):

Actually i got it,problem is with some_user database permission for using database in appengine(Localhost for cloud sql database).
FIX:
Type code in cloud sql database and execute

`grant all privileges on databasename.* to 'user'@'localhost' identified by 'password';`

This should help.........